# python 2.5 freeze.py import site failed

Tags: python, freeze

I am using python 2.5 and virtualenv to freeze an app. When I try to run the created executable I see the following error:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
```

I read an old thread in a mailing list saying it was a bug in `site.py` where it references `sys.path[-1]`. I edited `site.py` and added a check(e.g. `if len(sys.path) > 0`) but I still see that error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: use `-v` for traceback, inspect the traceback and post it if you can't figure it out.

Comment: there is no -v option for freeze.py or the compiled app

Comment: I don't think we can help without the traceback :c